# Django filtering by list of model objects

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, intersection, django-filter

I'm trying to filter a queryset by checking that the object is in a list of those objects.

```
employee_list = [<Employee: A>, <Employee: B>, <Employee: C>]
qs = Employee.objects.filter(id__in=employee_list, [other_filters])
```

After running above, qs is an empty list.  I was thinking that I could make a new list such as

```
employee_ids = [emp.id for emp in employee_list]
qs = Employee.objects.filter(id__in=employee_ids, [other_filters])
```

I haven't done benchmarking on this method, but I imagine performance would probably take a hit.  Alternatively I could intersect the lists afterwards like:

```
qs = Employee.objects.filter([other_filters])
filtered_qs = [emp for emp in employee_lids if emp in qs]
```

However, I think the performance hit would be even worse this way.

What's the best/fastest way to do this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Martol1ni noted you want to filter at the SQL level whenever possible so I think your methods do get progressively slower, but another issue...

Based on the Django Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/ I think your`id__in` should be a list of integer ids, not a list of models.

**Edit:**
Oh I see he covered this in his answer, but it was not explicit that it was incorrect in your question.

**Edit2:**
But yes, if you want to know for sure, what really matters is real world performance, which you can do with [django-debug-toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar/). It seems to me though the real issue was the `id__in` misuse which lead you to find trickier ways to do what you wanted to do.

Comment: I ran a profiler on each of the different methods, but didn't see too much a difference between them.  My test data set is much smaller than production, obviously, but constructing a list of id's from the list of objects and then filtering id__in id_list seemed to be the fastest.

Answer (score 2):

Rule of thumb is to filter as much as possible through SQL, so I would go for

```
qs = Employee.objects.filter(id__in=[emp.id for emp in employee_list], [other_filters])
```

I do not have any performance testing to back this up with though.

Comment: I may note this greatly depends on the size of both the queryset, the list and the use case